# C# generic factory method

Tags: c#, generics, factory

Perhaps this is a simple newbie C# question, but so be it---it will be a fresh break from my other questions, which are so difficult that no one knows the answer to them. :)

Let's say I have a generic type in C#:

```
Thing<T>
```

And let's say I want to make a thing using a static factory method. In Java, this is no problem:

```
public static <T> Thing<T> createThing()
{
  return flag ? new Thing<Integer>(5) : new Thing<String>("hello");
}
```

How do I do this in C#? Thanks.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? You're never using the generic type argument `T` in your code.

Comment: No matter what you do, that sort of construct is not possible in C#.  For starters, `Thing<int>` and `Thing<string>` are different types and you can only return a single type in a function.  Java doesn't have this problem due to its type erasure semantics.  It still is ultimately returning a `Thing`.

Comment: Can you add example code showing how you would call the `createThing()` method and how you would declare and use the returned value?

Comment: @Adam, if it makes you feel better, I could change the code to: public static Thing<?> createThing(){}. It has the same effect. I'm returning a thing, but I don't know at compile time what its generic argument is. The benefit of using an actual parameter in Java is that I could restrict what comes back---I could say public static <T extends MyBaseClass> Thing<T> createThing(), indicating that I don't know what the generic argument will be, but it will be MyBaseClass or some subclass of it.

Comment: @Enigmativity, in Java I would say Thing<?> thing=createThing(). Then later, when I figured out what the generic type is, I would cast it, e.g. Thing<String> stringThing=(Thing<String>)thing.

Comment: @Jeff, this isn't an erasure issue; erasure happens as a result of compilation, and what we're talking about here is the static type-safety checking that occurs during compilation (without regard to whether it gets erased later or not). Furthermore, the "different types" part of your statement seems to ignore the generic covariance introduced in C# 4. I think the real problem here has to do with the lack of wildcard types in C#.

Comment: @Garret: It seems to have *everything* to do with erasure; `Thing<Int>` and `Thing<String>` in Java are fundamentally the same type. The same is *not* true in any of the .NET languages. As far as the runtime is concerned, they are entirely different types.

Comment: @Adam, read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx and let me know if that is your final answer. Apparently C# allows this sort of thing if Thing<> is an an interface under certain conditions.

Comment: @Garret: Yes, it's certainly my final answer. `Thing<Int>` and `Thing<String>` are completely different types as far as the runtime is concerned. Yes, there is support for generic covariance and contravariance with interfaces, but a) it applies only to interfaces (your code implies a class), and b) you must still have a base type. You cannot have a "wildcard".

Comment: @Adam, I'm not disputing that they aren't different types, but my point is that C# could allow this to be compiled if it wanted to, even without erasure. In fact, as you mention, if I switch to interfaces this is allowed, as you pointed out. So yes, they are different types, but I'm saying that lack of erasure is not what's standing in the way. But anyway, see my separate answer, which I think is compatible with what you're saying. Thanks.

Comment: That actually looks like a poster child for what's wrong with Java generics. You call e.g. createThing<Runnable>(), and get back a Thing<Integer>?!  WTF?  I also don't see how C# could allow this to be compiled w/o introducing a non-generic type/interface and returning that.

Comment: @jonp, what you wrote isn't valid in C# nor in Java. If you specify a method will return Thing<Runnable>, then it must return Thing<Runnable>. However, in Java you could say that it returns Thing<? extends Runnable>, allowing you to return Thing<MyRunnable>, where MyRunnable implements Runnable---something not allowed in C# until C# 4, and even then only with interfaces under special conditions. I'll be the first to say that Java generics have shortcomings, but this isn't one of them---if anything, it is an area in which C# has been lagging. Both Java and C# have their WTFs. :)

Comment: FWIW, the Java code posted doesn't compile with the default settings as you claimed.  The static analysis recognizes that `Thing<Integer>` and `Thing<String>` are not of type `Thing<T>` and fails.  Casting each to `Thing<T>` gets it to compile but doesn't help with the type safety or getting it to work (without major changes to the type definitions) in C#.

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, yes you're correct---you have to use a cast. But you could do the same thing without the cast using a wildcard. For instance, you could do public static <T extends Number> List<T> createThing() or public static List<? extends Number> createThing(), with similar results, except that no cast is needed on the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return an instance of a templated class using one of many different template arguments, one way to do it is with an abstract base (or an interface):

```
abstract class UntypedThing { }
class Thing<T> : UntypedThing
{
    public Thing(T t) { }
}

class Foo
{
    public static UntypedThing createThing(bool flag)
    {
        if (flag)
            return new Thing<int>(5);
        else return new Thing<String>("hello");
    }
}
```

The `UntypedThing` class would contain as much code as possible that does not rely on the template type. The `Thing` class would ideally only contain code that relies on the template type. The factory class `Foo` always returns the former.

Comment: To be clear, I think the answer is that C# does not allow this sort of thing (even though Java does) because of C#'s limitations on covariant generics and the lack of C# generic wildcards; but Reinderien's answer is the most reasonable workaround. Cheers!

Comment: What happens when you want your interface/abstract class to have a method that included the parameterised type in the method signature, such as public T GetTypedFoo()? The public inteface, whether abstract class or actual interface, needs to know about the type.

Comment: Since the type-specific information in this case is intended to be relegated to the child classes, it seems like anti-design to want some `GetTypedFoo` in the abstract base. However, it's possible using reflection information stored in the base, if you really want that.

Answer (score 4):

You can in theory use reflection to build up the correct generic type, but it will be pretty useless to you as at some point you will need to upcast it to a less specific type.

```
public class ThingFactory  {
    public object Create(bool flag) {
        Type outputType = null;
        if(flag) {
            outputType = typeof(string);
        } else {
            outputType = typeof(int);
        }
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Thing<>).MakeGenericType(outputType));
    }
}
```

As you can see, the value of doing this is about zero as you will need to cast the return type to the type you want, meaning that the logic to determine it needs to live outside the `Create` method.

I would use Reinderien's method and have a non-generic base. This is the most sane and idiomatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the trouble I get myself in when I simply try to do something simple.

It turns out that [C# 4 allows this sort of covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx)---sort of. First, I have to make Thing an interface and specify the "out" generic parameter:

```
public interface Thing<out T> {...}
```

But if I do certain things, C# won't let me use covariance. For example, if I try to return T from the interface:

```
public interface Thing<out T>
{
  public T GetT();
```

Even if I manage to get covariance with Thing, what do I do with it?

```
Thing<object> thing=createThing();
```

The compiler tells me that the type cannot be inferred from usage.

Let's say I say screw the whole T thing and make the factory method return Thing of type object:

```
public static Thing<object> createThing() {...}
```

Fine, but now where do I put it?

```
IList<Thing<object>> list=new List<Thing<object>>();
Thing<object> thing=createThing();
list.Add(thing);
```

Yes, I have to say that this is a list of Thing with T of type Object, because C# has no wildcard type.

If this were Java, I'd simply say:

```
public class Thing<T> {...}

public static <T> Thing<T> createThing() {...}

List<?> things=new ArrayList<Thing<?>>();
Thing<?> thing=createThing();
things.add(thing);
```

If I wanted extra safety by saying that T had to be of a special type, I'd say:

```
public static <T extends MyBaseType> Thing<T> createThing() {...}

List<? extends MyBaseType> things=new ArrayList<Thing<? extends MyBaseType>>();
Thing<? extends MyBaseType> thing=createThing();
things.add(thing);
```

Then I'd figure out what T is later, when I had more information.

This all seems to come down to incomplete generic covariance in C# coupled with the lack of C# generic wildcards. (I still maintain it isn't an erasure issue.)

So what do I do? The only simple thing to do seems to follow Reinderien's answer and split out a non-generic base class.

(I wonder if in this non-generic base class I could have object getValue() and then use covariance in the subclass to return T getValue()? Ack, I'm tired of this---I'll leave that for another day.)

Comment: What you're seeking is not covariance. The ability to specify a wildcard is made possible *only* by type erasure. A generic type without any of its generic arguments specified as *something* simply does not exist within the .NET runtime. Even with covariance and contravariance, you must specify a type that the compiler can use to compare to the specified type in order to determine compatibility. It's not that it's an incomplete implementation, it's that what you're asking for simply isn't co/contra-variance at all.

Comment: @Adam, I'm trying to understand here. I can have a method with a signature returning interface Thing<object>. Within that method, I can return Thing<int> or Thing<string>. If I understand correctly, this works now with C# 4. How is that different than Java having Thing<?> (which is short for Thing<? extends object>) in the signature? Isn't the common generic type here "object"?

Comment: Your specific example is incorrect (variance applies only to reference types, not to value types like `int`), though the general sentiment is right. Yes, you could use `Thing<object>` as a safe container for any reference type, assuming that `T` is marked appropriately. You can't, however, safely downcast to a more specific `Thing`.